# Are race conditions possible in SQL?

Tags: locking, blocking

I would like to understand what the SQL standard says about parallel queries and race conditions. If there is no standard, then I would be interested in the approach adopted by popular databases.

I understand that 2+ read-only queries can run in parallel, but can a read/write or write/write pair run in parallel as well?

For example, suppose a simple aggregation such as

```
SELECT AVG(col1) FROM tbl;
```

And while that is running, I will issue an

```
INSERT INTO tbl (col1) VALUES (3);
```

Is the `INSERT` executed while the `SELECT` is running or will the `INSERT` be blocked until execution finishes?

In other words, are race-conditions possible in SQL?

Additionally, I would appreciate a discussion on how row, page and table locks are used in this context.

Thanks

Comment: I see two questions.  the first one ("are race-conditions possible?") would deal with "Isolation Levels".  The second "how row,page, and table locks are used?" is most likely RDBMS dependent and should probably be a separate question. (I believe "discussions" are not permitted on this site)

Answer (score 1):

According to the SQL standard a single SQL query sees a consistent state of the table(s) it operates on. So it must not see any changes while it's running. But not all DBMS products completely comply with that (notably those that allow dirty reads). For example Postgres or Oracle will not block the `INSERT` while the `SELECT` is running (or vice versa). But different DBMS do behave differently in that situation depending on their configuration. - [a-horse-with-no-name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name)

Answer (score 1):

What the SQL standard has to say about concurrency is the definition of *transaction isolation levels*. Depending on which one you choose, you get certain guarantees. I won't quote the standard, since this answer should be readable, but this is a paraphrase of the definitions:

- **`READ UNCOMMITTED`**: No guarantees.
- **`READ COMMITTED`**: You are guaranteed not to get any *dirty reads*, i.e., you won't see data from a transaction that is not yet committed.
- **`REPEATABLE READ`**: In addition to the above, you are guaranteed not to experience *non-repeatable reads*, i.e., if you run the same query a second time withing the transaction, none of the result rows can be gone or modified by concurrent transactions.
- **`SERIALIZABLE`**: Concurrent execution of several transactions can never produce a result that is different from a certain serial execution of the same transactions.

  This implies that you are safe from *phantom reads*, i.e. new rows appearing during the second execution of the same query within one transaction.

You will notice that all but the last definition are negative, that is, you are not guaranteed a certain behavior. For example, if you choose `READ UNCOMMITTED`, you are not guaranteed to get dirty reads (and in many implementations you won't, like in PostgreSQL and Oracle).

The SQL standard decrees that `SERIALIZABLE` is the default transaction isolation level, but many databases have `READ COMMITTED` by default (for performance reasons).

So the answer to your **question about race conditions** is: Yes, you can get race conditions, depending on the isolation level you are using. Only if you use `SERIALIZABLE`, you are safe from race conditions. (I should remark that this does **not** apply to Oracle, whose `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level does not live up to its name.)

The answer to the question **how this is implemented with locks** cannot be given in general, as it differs significantly between the various implementations. However, there are two fundamental techniques:

1. **read locks:** every read and write takes locks that block each other. The higher the isolation level, the more locks are taken. The exact type of lock is implementation dependent.
2. **multiversioning:** no read locks are taken, and reader and writers do not block each other. The old versions of a modified table row are kept around for concurrent read requests to conform to the guarantees of the isolation levels.